# How to segment femoral and tibial knee cartilage individualy?

Tags: matlab

I am researching in medical image processing area. I want to segment knee cartilage into femoral cartilage and tibial cartilage. But two part have same intensity and only different position(femoral cartilage is above and tibial cartilage is below). I am finding the techniques or method to segment them individualy.Could you help me show to me that techniques? Thank you so much![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to do some motion tracking of points to separate the two. Is it possible to take images before and after some motion? That way you could model how the cartilage moved as a function of tibia or femoral motion, and you might be able to separate what portions of the cartilage belong to the tibia and femur.

Comment: It is impossible. I only have one input that is above knee image. Do you have any idea or method?

Comment: Well, the only way I can think of is to move the tibia (or femur) a predetermined angle. Then you can use likely use some sort of pixel tracking algorithm. The cartilage corresponding with the tibia and femur should mimic this motion. I think your solution is using motion.

Comment: Do you have any paper to explain it? Note that I only show one image. But for one people has 160 slices to make 3D segmentation.

Comment: I don't have a specific paper to explain it as I have never needed to do this. However, I am pretty sure there are tracking algorithms to do what you need. You'll have to do some literature searching to find a paper.